# Adding custom capability in "Members" Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, user-roles

I'm trying to add a custom capability to the "Shop Manager" role using the "Members" plugin in Wordpress. I have installed a plugin called "New Order Notification", that allows the Store to receive live notifications when orders are made... The thing is that the "Shop Manager" role can't see that plugin and obviously, no notifications are shown...

Can someone help me to add a custom capability to the "Members" plugin? I have tried many as: new_order_notification ; read_new_order_notification ; edit_new_order_notification but none of them seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same thing. It looks like it's pretty simple if you register a new capability in functions.php. Check it out...

[https://memberpress.com/plugins/members/docs/#:~:text=If%20you%27re%20a%20plugin%20developer%20with%20custom%20capabilities%2C,human-readable%20form%20%28e.g.%2C%20Publish%20Posts%20instead%20of%20publish_posts%29](https://memberpress.com/plugins/members/docs/#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20a%20plugin%20developer%20with%20custom%20capabilities%2C,human-readable%20form%20%28e.g.%2C%20Publish%20Posts%20instead%20of%20publish_posts%29).